# resizing a div element for a timeframe after a button is clicked. Do i use javascript or is there an easier way

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i a wondering what is the best way to resize a div for a time frame say 5 seconds after a button is clicked. what is the best solution to do this javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1):

**You will have to use javascript in order to do anything on the button click.**

If it was me - I would add a class to the div on the click, and set a time out to remove the class. The class would have the altered styling that would affect the size of the div. In this demo - I am making the target div twice as big for a time of 2 seconds and then reoving the class to return the div back to ormal.

Note that there are numerous ways to alter the size of the div, but you will need to use javascript to trigger them. You don't need the jQuery library just this though- straight js can do it. You should investigate some of the funky CSS ways to affecting DOM elements to get a nice smooth transition or altertion.

```js
function alterSize(type) {
 var targetDiv = document.querySelector("#target-div");
 targetDiv.classList.add(type);
 setTimeout(function(){
  targetDiv.classList.remove(type);
  }, 2000)
}
```

```css
#target-div {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border: solid 1px blue;
background: #efefef;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#target-div.small {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}

#target-div.large {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="alterSize('small')">Click me to decrease the size</button>

<button type="button" onclick="alterSize('large')">Click me to increase the size</button>
<hr/>
<div id="target-div">
```

Comment: thankyou so much for your help and input ill look into it :)